# Figure of oscillation of an object between two hemispheres of a spherical earth with no friction (under corilois and centrifugal force)

Tags: classical-mechanics

I had hard time on a difficult and interesting problem which i invented to challenge myself. This problem asks for complete description of the motion of an object on a fictitous spherical world with no forces acting on the object except gravity, the normal to the surface, and the centrifugal and coriolis forces (in earth's frame).

Suppose the the object is initially at rest at latitude $\lambda_0$ (suppose for simplicity that this angle is a small angle). Since there is no friction, the object begins to accelerate under the influence of the tangential component of the centrifugal force, and, as he starts to move, the coriolis force begins to play its role. For small enough $\lambda_0$, obviously the object will pass through the equator to the other hemisphere, and from there will return to its initial position, and vice versa. The object will therfore oscillate in a non-trivial pattern which i have great difficulty to imagine  - sometimes i think it's the figure "8" (perhaps a kind of lemniscate curve) and sometimes i'm not even sure if it will trace a closed loop at all. When neglecting coriolis force, the problem is obviously that of harmonic oscillator.

In order to help those who want to help me - i've add an equation for the velocity of the object in earth's frame of reference. Since coriolis force isn't doing any work, the only factor effecting this velocity is it's distance from earth's axis of rotation (equivalently, the work done by centrifugal force). Therefore, for initial latitude $\lambda_0$, the object speed is:

$$v(\lambda) = \Omega R \sqrt{{cos^2\lambda - cos^2\lambda_0}}\approx \Omega R \sqrt{{\lambda^2_0 - \lambda^2}}$$

Any help will be blessed!

Comment: Probably show a little work towards your speed equation. Coriolis really is a vector force, so you need to show a cross product to get in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's a difficult problem.

In the case you describe the motion will *not* end up as a closed loop.

Here is the strategy to see why that is the case:

Since this is the idealized case of no friction the motion of the object over the sphere, once released, is along a [great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle).

In general that motion along a great circle will not have the same period as the rotation of the sphere underneath it.

In order for the motion along the great circle to have a period of one day the angular velocity in the plane of that great circle must be one circumnavigation per day.

Let's say the motion along the great circle starts at 60 degrees latitude. The cosine of 60 degrees is 0.5; hence the tangential velocity prior to release is half of what the tangential velocity is if the object would be located at the equator.

In order to make the object do a circumnavitation in one day on release (from 60 deg. latitude) it needs a big eastward velocity relative to its point of release.

With precisely the right initial eastward velocity (relative to the point of release) the motion with respect to the Earth will be a closed curve; the lemniscate figure that you mentioned.

The motion along the great circle has been set up to have a period of one day, therefore the object will be back at the same point after a full day. The Earth has also completed precisely one period, so the poitn of release is back at the same position too.

In all other cases:
For instance, if you release without any initial velocity (relative to the point of release) then the actual initial velocity is the *velocity* of circumnavigating the Earth's axis at the starting latitude. That velocity is slower than the velocity of circumnavitating the Earth's axis at the equator, therefore the period of the motion along the great circle will be longer than a day. And that means the motion with respect to the Earth will not be closed curve.

---

Some years ago I created a simulation to treat exactly this case. (I used a simulation creating platform called EJS.) The generated simulation requires Java to run. For more information see the following page on my website: 
[Great Circles](http://www.cleonis.nl/physics/ejs/great_circles_simulation.php)

In that simulation the calculations proceed as follows: first the motion with respect to the non-rotating coordinate system: the great circle. For the motion with respect to the rotating sphere: a rotation of the position vector around the axis of the rotating coordinate system.

The motion with respect to the non-rotating coordinate system is straightforward: uniform motion along a great circle. Rotating the position vector to the rotating coordinate system is straightforward too.